# Why does Play() on media element reset or otherwise ignore set position?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mediaelement

I want to pause and play a mp3 using 2 buttons like this:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan time_input = media.Position;
    media.Pause();
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    media.Play();
    media.Position = time_input;
}
```

but clicking the second button plays media from beginning instead of from time_input span why?

Comment: What happens if you reverse the order of Media.Play() and Media.Position?  Set position first and then play.

Comment: i tried that,but same problem starts from begining.

Comment: Looks like it should do it automatically as long as the media is the active object.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position.aspx)

Comment: i didn't understood what you said

Comment: if i set TimeSpan time_input = new TimeSpan( 0, 1, 0);//it jumps to 1st minute.

Answer (score 0):

In `Button_Click_1` method `TimeSpan time_input = media.Position;` will create a new `time_input` variable within the scope of that method. You won't be able to use it in the other method.

```
private TimeSpan time_input = new TimeSpan(0);
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    time_input = media.Position;
    media.Pause();
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    media.Play();
    media.Position = time_input;
}
```